# 'User' object is not iterable in Django 1.11.8

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model that have a `ManyToManyField` for users, and I want to record logged in user when he/she submits the form in `Choice` model, but this code is stopping me from doing so. I used the `login_required` decorator to force user to login first (that's what I want actually).

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

QUESTION_CHOICES = (
        ("choice_1", "Choice 1"),
        ("choice_2", "Choice 2"),
        ("choice_3", "Choice 3"),
    )


class Choice(models.Model):
    users   = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    choices = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=QUESTION_CHOICES, unique=True)
    vote    = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choices + " " + "-" + " " + str(self.vote)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Choice

@login_required
def index(request):
    food = request.POST.get('sunday')
    user_v = None
    get_choices = Choice.objects.values('choices', 'vote')

    new_choices = list(get_choices)

    for q in new_choices:
        choice = q['choices']
        vote_v   = q['vote']

        if food:
            if food == choice:
                if request.user.is_authenticated():
                    user_v = request.user
                    print(user_v)               # it prints out correctly after sucessful form submit
                vote_v += 1
                model_conn = Choice.objects.get(choices=choice)
                model_conn.vote = vote_v
                model_conn.users = user_v       # this is where I get an error
                model_conn.save()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ManyToMany field for users so need to use `add` method to add current user to the users list:

```
model_conn.users.add(user_v)
```

If you need to clear related users list first you can use `clear`:

```
model_conn.users.clear()
model_conn.users.add(user_v)
```